# Writing a value to two tables in access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have two tables in Access 2016 with one to one relationship and I want when entering a value (integer) on the fist one i.e "service report Number" to automatically set it on the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an "update query" to accomplish your need